# Jar created from ant not able to find external jars

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have created an executable jar file via ant, which also referring to `mysql-connector.jar`, an external jar file.
When I do java -jar *.jar, it executes but gives `ClassNotFoundException` on all SQL related statements. I have followed the steps given in [Ant Tutorial](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).

Database is getting created successfully if I do `ant compile` & `ant run`.
How do I make it run via jar file?

**build.xml**

```
<project name="OMSInstaller" basedir="." >

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

        <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
        <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
        <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
        <property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>
        <property name="main-class"  value="Installer.OMSinstaller"/>
     <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </path>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

     <target name="jar" depends="compile">
            <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
            <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
                <manifest>
                    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
                </manifest>
            </jar>
        </target>

     <target name="run" depends="jar">
            <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="classpath"/>
                    <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
                </classpath>
            </java>
        </target>


</project>
```

**lib folder:**

mysql-connector-java-*.jar

jtds-*.jar

Comment: From memory, when you execute jars (java -jar), java will ignore the class path attributes passed to it, instead it will use the jars class-path manifest attribute. You should be adding any dependencies that your main jar depends on to the jars manifest

Comment: Oh okay. As I have created a jar from ant's build file, is there anyway to pass manifest file as parameter in build.xml so that it get's included in jar . If no, then how should I specify manifest file to already created jar?

Comment: You can build the classpath dynamically based on a directory full of jars and add it to the generated manifest. See the ant documentation on how to do that

Comment: found an old ant file where I did something similar, have to add an answer because it is too long for a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found an old ant file of mine where i build the classpath string automatically and add it to the manifest of the generated class file

```
<target name="BuildJar">
    <property name="liblocation" location="${libdir}" />
    <pathconvert property="jarclasspathstring" pathsep=" ">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${liblocation}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <map from="${liblocation}" to="." />
    </pathconvert>
    <jar destfile="${builddir}/${jarname}" basedir="${bindir}" update="true" level="9" index="false" filesOnly="true">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${mainclass}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jarclasspathstring}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

libdir is a property specifying a directory where all your referenced libaries are

PS: index=false is important if you want to reference other jar files

Comment: Thanks for sharing build file. I managed to create jar file . But now when I run it , it says `no main attribute, in *.jar` . I extracted the jar and checked the META-INF folder for manifest file. It does have entry `Main-Class: Installer.OMSinstaller
Class-Path: OMSInstaller-*.jar`

Comment: are the Main-Class and Class-Path really in one line? They should be in separate ones

Also, the Class-Path entry must not contain a wildcard! all files must be listed explicitly. If you have generated it with my code, and you still end up with a wildcard in your entry, this may be because there are no jar files to reference, i.e., ant does not look into the right folder?

Comment: No, Main-Class and Class-Path were on separate lines. Also there is no wildcard in class-path,. But yes I was giving wrong location for jars. Now issue is solved. Thanks!